# Proving $CD$ is perpendicular to $AB$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider two points $A$ and $B$ in plane. Let $C$ and $D$ be two points such that
$$(AC)^2-(BC)^2=(AD)^2-(BD)^2$$
Can we conclude or prove that $CD$ perpendicular t0 $AB$?

I think the answer is yes, but I need some hints to prove that according to assumption of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In triangle $ABC$, $AC^2-BC^2=AB^2-2\cdot AB\cdot BC\cdot \cos B_1$.

In triangle $ABD$, $AD^2-BD^2=AB^2-2\cdot AB\cdot BD\cdot \cos B_2$.

So $BC\cdot \cos B_1=BD\cdot \cos B_2$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting from the converse statement:

> If $CD$ is perpendicular to $AB$, then $(AC)^2 - (BC)^2 = (AD)^2 - (BD)^2$

See if you can prove this. (Note that by the wording of the statement, this converse statement does not need to always be true for the original statement to hold. But in this situation, it does).

Then modify the first part of the above statement to consider the complementary cases:

> If $CD$ is at some angle ($\neq 90$) to $AB$, then does $(AC)^2 - (BC)^2 = (AD)^2 - (BD)^2?$

If you can show this is always false, then you've proven the original statement by contrapositive (if $\neg q \implies \neg p$, then $p \implies q$). To do this, start with the same approach you did for the converse statement. But obviously something will change in the proof, and that should help you see a reason why this statement fails.

More specific hints for this problem:

> For the converse statement, try proving $(AC)^2 + (BD)^2 = (BC)^2 + (AD)^2$. Then for the second statement, try proving $\Delta \equiv \left( (AC)^2 + (BD)^2 \right) - \left( (BC)^2 + (AD)^2 \right) \neq 0$ when the angle between $CD$ and $AB$ is not 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume [wlog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality), up to a translation, rotation and scaling, that $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(1,0)$ therefore by $C=(a,b)$ and $D=(c,d)$ the given identity
$$(AC)^2-(BC)^2=(AD)^2-(BD)^2 $$

becomes

$$a^2+b^2-\left[(a-1)^2+b^2\right]=c^2+d^2-\left[(c-1)^2+d^2\right]$$

that is

$$2a-1=2c-1 \iff a=c$$

which implies $CD\perp AB$, unless $C=D$.

Comment: The way I read your argument is that if we set up our coordinate system so that points $A$ and $B$ are distinct points on the $x$-axis, then points $C$ and $D$ lie on the same vertical line, which guarantees $\overline{AB} \perp \overline{CD}$ unless $C = D$.  What is the significance of the statement $|a| + |c| > 0$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Exactly, beeing the identity invariant under isometry and scaling. The given condition is necessary to avoid that all points are aligned.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I think that the condition "unless $C=D$" is better!

Answer (score 0):

I used the idea of user**1172706** for an alternative solution.

Let $X$ be the intersection of the line segments $AB$ and $CD$ and $\angle AXC=\alpha$. Then law of cosines on the four resulting triangles gives
$$AC^2=XA^2+XC^2-2XAXC\cos\alpha\tag 1$$
$$BC^2=XB^2+XC^2+2XBXC\cos\alpha\tag 2$$
$$AD^2=XA^2+XD^2+2XAXD\cos\alpha\tag 3$$
$$BD^2=XB^2+XD^2-2XBXD\cos\alpha\tag 4$$
From $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$,
$$AC^2-BC^2=XA^2-XB^2-2ABXC\cos\alpha\tag 5$$
$$AD^2-BD^2=XA^2-XB^2+2ABXD\cos\alpha\tag 6$$
Since $AC^2-BC^2=AD^2-BD^2$, from $(6,5)$ we get
$-XC\cos\alpha=XD\cos\alpha$, in other words $CD\cos\alpha=0$. This implies that $\cos\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=90^{\circ}$.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative by vectors and scalar product

$$(AC)^2-(BC)^2=(AD)^2-(BD)^2 \iff \vec{AC}\cdot \vec{AC}-\vec{BC}\cdot \vec{BC}=\vec{AD}\cdot \vec{AD}-\vec{BD}\cdot \vec{BD}$$

and then

$$\left( \vec{AC}-\vec{BC}\right)\cdot\left( \vec{AC}+\vec{BC}\right)=\left( \vec{AD}-\vec{BD}\right)\cdot\left( \vec{AD}+\vec{BD}\right)$$

$$\left( \vec{AC}+\vec{CB}\right)\cdot\left( \vec{AC}+\vec{BC}\right)=\left( \vec{AD}+\vec{DB}\right)\cdot\left( \vec{AD}+\vec{BD}\right)$$

$$\vec{AB}\cdot\left( \vec{AC}+\vec{BC}\right)=\vec{AB}\cdot\left( \vec{AD}+\vec{BD}\right)$$

$$\vec{AB}\cdot\left( \vec{AC}-\vec{AD}\right)=\vec{AB}\cdot\left( -\vec{BC}+\vec{BD}\right)$$

$$\vec{AB}\cdot\left( \vec{DA}+\vec{AC}\right)=\vec{AB}\cdot\left( \vec{CB}+\vec{BD}\right)$$

$$\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{DC}=\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{CD}$$

which requires

$$\vec{AB}=\vec{0}\;\lor\;\vec{DC}=\vec{0}\;\lor\; \vec{AB}\perp\vec{CD}$$